An algorithm for finding all invariant subspaces of a linear operator over finite field in general case.
Let A be a $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.
$\chi_A(x)$ is a characteristic polynomial of $A$.
I'm considering a map $\phi_A \colon v \mapsto vA, v\in V$ and trying to find all invariant subspaces of linear map corresponding to $\phi_{A}$ (or $A$). There is an algorithm what I figure out:

compute canonical form of characteristic polynomial
$$
\chi_A(x) = f^{k_1}_1(x)\cdot\ldots\cdot f^{k_r}_r(x)
$$
decompose $V$ into direct sum of kernels
$$
V = \ker f^{k_1}_1(A) \dotplus \ldots \dotplus \ker f^{k_r}_r(x)
$$
Let $\psi_i = \phi |_{\ker f^{k_i}_i(A)}$ be a restriction of $\phi_A$.
Compute a list $L_{i}$ of all invariant subspaces of $\psi_i$, $i=1,\ldots,r$.
(here I could use brute force)
Compute all linear combinations of elements from lists: $\{V_1 + \ldots + V_r | V_i \in L_i\} = W$
Return W

So did I count every invariant subspaces of $\phi_A$? If not how can I improve the algorithm?
